# ResourcesNotFoundException: File res/layout/progress_dialog.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, progressdialog

I am getting the following crash log showing progress_dialog.xml is missing on showing a ProgressDialog.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/progress_dialog.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x109007a
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2152)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2107)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:857)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:165)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:415)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:284)
at com.company.game.MyClass$5.run(MyClass.java:333)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4477)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/layout/progress_dialog.xml
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2134)
... 17 more
```

I am not using a custom ProgressDialog. I have given the code below:

```
public static ProgressDialog mActivityInticator = null;

public static void ShowActivityInticator() 
{ 
  MyActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
  { 
    @Override 
    public void run() 
    { 
      if(mActivityInticator == null) 
      { 
        mActivityInticator = new ProgressDialog(context); 
        mActivityInticator.setMessage("Loading..."); 
        mActivityInticator.setCancelable(false); 
      } 
      mActivityInticator.show(); 
    } 
  }); 
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it is crashing in some devices.

Comment: We dont see in your source where you are refering to progress_dialog.xml, please post the relevant code.

Comment: @LazyNinja that xml is returned by getbaseContext() method it is his activity xml if iam correct

Comment: change `getBaseContext()` to `Classname.this`

Comment: @LazyNinja I am not using this XML that is the issue.

Comment: @glo have you tried to clean your project and build it again? I find it weird that it is working some devices.

Comment: @LazyNinja I cannot reproduce this crash. I got the crash reports from play store.

Comment: Where does `context` come from? Is it possible that it's no longer the active context after a configuration change event such as orientation change?

Comment: @laalto no i have handled all configuration changes and it is an active context

Comment: @glo what is your min sdk set to? If it is <8 it won't work.

Comment: @Lukos My minimum SDK version is 10

Comment: In the generated R file, what is 0x109007a?

Comment: Also, on what devices is it crashing? What API level are they? Are they the same model? Are they using a custom rom?

Comment: @rds The crash seems to come from various devices but the device that I found crash is Samsung Galaxy tab 2 and it does not have a custom rom

Comment: @glo,have you check dependency of this progress_dialog xml file in you project ?

Comment: Try cleaning and then going in File->Invalidade Caches and Restart and trying again

Comment: Please show the code which assigns `context`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Since you are using `cpp` and getting xml exception it may be a problem of setting some property value in setting. Another fix is use `getParent()` instead of `context`. and also give a null check in it

Use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
       //your code
    }
});
```

not as in your comment

Comment: My game is in cpp. I am showing the progress dialog until I get a signal from cpp side of my code. So I cannot use AsyncTask

Comment: I do not think that would cause a ResourceNotFoundException in Java side of my code. This is a simple ProgressDialog.

Comment: I had made a change in my question. I am not using 'getBaseContext()'. I call the function from a class that doesn't extend Activity. I do use 'this' to save 'Context' into variable 'context'

Comment: from where did you call this ShowActivityInticator()

Comment: I call this function from different points and I run it from main thread. I did not give the whole function as it didn't seem necessary.

Comment: Whats the exact line causing the problem , check it with logcat

Comment: if mActivityInticator.show() is the line causing problem then you are either not in the same context or you are out of UI thread.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41842/discussion-between-glo-and-arju)